# How do I convert the following data serialization format into POJO or JSON?

Tags: json, string, serialization, data-structures

I was expecting a JSON string while testing an API using Postman, but instead got this:

`{city=Shanghai, work=112-454-7895, fax=788-899-7899}`

Obviously I cannot put that into Google and ask what format is it, hence I am asking it here. Postman also says it is a 'bad string'.

I have never seen the above data serialization format. If someone can point the format out to me I would be able to find and use a converter. Additional suggestion with converting it to POJO or JSON are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the above format is a stringified version of a `HashMap<String, String>`, and that there is no direct way to convert it into JSON/POJO. Converting it into json string requires additional work but is fairly straightforward.